# liquibase: check for compound indexes by columns

Tags: database, indexing, liquibase

We are trying to check in a liquibase precondition if a compound index already exists, before we create it. Reason is: the company we sold the software to ran optimization changesets on our db, which we now want to include in our db as well. But we do not know the name of the indexes that they used.

We have this so far:

```
<changeSet id="changeset-id" author="great-author">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <and>
                <indexExists indexName="idx_fields"/>
                <indexExists tableName="my_table" columnNames="id,name"/>
            </and>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createIndex tableName="my_table" indexName="idx_fields">
        <column name="id"/>
        <column name="name"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

now when the customer ran this change manually on this db:

```
create index company_schema.IDX1_FIELDS on company_schema.MY_TABLE("ID", "NAME") TABLESPACE USERS;
```

Then our changesets are failing and deployment is stuck.

Seems like our second precondition that is checking for a compound index by column names is not working.

Who can help us here?

Comment: Looks like there is no solution to this problem. You can check indexes only by name, not by column. At least I found no other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the built-in indexExists precondition isn't working with multi-columns indexes, your best option would be to use `<sqlCheck>` with a custom SQL query that uses the database metadata views to look for the index correctly.

What that query is exactly will depend on the database.

Comment: I agree. I didn't check if it works this way though, but sounds like the way to go. We use the names of the indexes now in the precondition. Thanks for your reply!